# Android Intent Filter doesn't not send me the entire url

Tags: android, intentfilter

I did setup an Intent Filter to react to that kind of link :
https://compagny.work.me/plop/X?af_dp=Y&Z

Where
https://compagny.work.me/plop/ is always the same, but X, Y, Z are var.

My intent filter:

```
<intent-filter  android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="https"
           android:host="compagny.work.me"
           android:pathPrefix="/plop" />
</intent-filter>
```

When my activity is start the URI in the Intent got only plop/X in the path and nothing behind '?'. How can i send the entire path? I try many thing with pathPattern but nothing seems to work.

Even better then a solution if someone has a great post on this subject I would appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

> When my activity is start the URI in the Intent got only plop/X in the path and nothing behind '?'

That is because everything after the `?` is not part of the path. Those are query parameters.

> How can i send the entire path?

Call methods on `Uri` like `getQueryParameter()` to read a value from a query parameter.